# Getting yesterday's NSDate start and end

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I have looked through a few similar questions on here, but they address slightly different issues than what I'm trying to do.  I want to create an `NSDate` object for the beginning and end of yesterday (12:00am - 12:00am). I have successfully created an `NSDate` for the start of the day and the end of the day, but I can only do it for the current day, not the previous day.  This doesn't seem like it should be much more difficult, but I've run into some trouble with it.

My start and end `NSDate` for the current day:

```
extension NSDate {

    var startOfDay: NSDate {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(self)
    }

    var endOfDay: NSDate? {
        let components = NSDateComponents()
        components.day = 1
        components.second = -1
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: startOfDay, options: NSCalendarOptions())
    }
}
```

I've tried adding something like this:

```
var yesterday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: -1, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)
```

But I get an error

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

.  I'm clearly missing something important here, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Comment: `.CalendarUnitDay` is invalid, it's just `.Day`. You also can't pass nil to the last parameter, it isn't optional. Try this: `var yesterday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -1, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))`

Comment: Btw, there is a full second after 23:59:59 that still counts to that day. 23:59:59.100 is today, and 23:59:59.99999999999 is today as well. You should use the beginning of the next day as the end of day to avoid missing that second. If you want to test if date is Today, you want to test that `date >= startOfDay && date < startOfNextDay`

Comment: Just use the start of the next day as the endOfDay

Comment: Sometimes the day starts at 1am, not 12am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some extensions I drag around. Plop the following in a play and enjoy:

```
import UIKit

extension NSDate {
    var yesterday:NSDate {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        return calendar.startOfDayForDate(calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -1, toDate: self, options: NSCalendarOptions.WrapComponents)!)
    }

    var tomorrow:NSDate {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        return calendar.startOfDayForDate(calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: self, options: NSCalendarOptions.WrapComponents)!)
    }
}


let now = NSDate()
now.yesterday
now.tomorrow
now.yesterday.yesterday.yesterday.yesterday
now.tomorrow.yesterday
```